# Redux reducer for inserting/removing elements from array and replace array

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux

I'm new to Redux and I have a question about the best practice to write a reducer for

1. inserting/removing an element to/from an array; and
2. replacing the array itself with another array

This is what I'm currently having:

```
const arrayReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_ELEM:
            return [...state, action.payload];  // payload expected to be an element
        case REMOVE_ELEM:
            return state.filter(
                elem => (elem.id !== action.payload.id)  // payload also expected to be an element
            );
        case UPDATE_ARRAY:
            return action.payload;  // payload expected to be an array?
        default:
            return state;
    }
```

The problem with my code is that, as the comments specified, the inconsistency of the type of `action.payload`. Is there a better way to structure this type of reducer?

Thanks everyone.

P.s: Thanks for the answers. I come from a Python/Java background so things that take different types based on different use cases are quite new to me.

Comment: what you mean by the inconsistency of the type of ```action.payload```

Comment: This is not inconsistency of the type of `action.paylod`. In javascript, your argument `action` (or rather its property `payload`) can be one time array and other time object, string, boolean, or anything else.

As @YevgenGorbunkov demonstrated in his answer, it only depends in what way you dispatched your action. This is not problem, this is how javascript works.

Comment: @SDushan I made an edit to address your questions.

Comment: As was commented in the answer below, `push` and `splice` will modify an array in place and violate redux immutability.  Your reducer looks fine to me other than probably wanting it to be an object with a property that has an array (which would then obviously require updates to the reducer)